# How to put Array List of Strings in text fields

Tags: java, arrays

Let's say I have a method that return with an array of strings "arr1" its size "s=arr1.size" and I have also some Text Fields lets say (JtextField1,JTextField2,JTextField3....)
now I want to put each String in this array in each Text Field 
how can I do it?

Comment: Really each string in each TextField? Oder every String in one Textfield?

Comment: How would I know the number of strings?
I dont know the size of array

Comment: How would you know the number of JTextField(s) then?

Comment: I've already created about 100 JTextField(S)
It's ok if i let most of them blank

Comment: I have not used Swing or AWT in about 10 years now, but a quick search of the `TextField` class in the java docs reveals a `setText` method which specifies the text for the text field.  Have you tried it?  Details here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html#setText(java.lang.String)

Comment: Sure I know setText method I use it more than my name
It's just just I dont know how much Strings i have from the array

Comment: Check the `.length` property of an array.  Or just use a foreach loop.  `for (String s : strings)`.